# CORS Angular and SpringBoot - request blocked

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I have a problem that I don't seem to figure out.
I want to send a http request from my

Angular client:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api';
console.log(this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => this.greeting = data));
```

to SpringBoot backend where I use CORS annotation:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/", maxAge = 3600)
    @RequestMapping("/api/")
    public Map<String,Object> home() {
        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
    }
```

but I'm getting an error that it's blocked and redirects me to login all the time.

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/api: Redirect from 'http://localhost:8080/api' to 'http://localhost:8080/login' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is there a way to change that?

I appreciate any hint or help regarding this. I would like to understand why this problem is happening.

Comment: Have you tried adding CORS to `/login`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have error in  your `RequestMapping`, as you have used `@RequestMapping("/api/")`, this will be evaluated as `http://your_url/api//`. Such mapping is not present in your controller, hence it is giving you CORS Origin error.

Just remove trailing `/` from `@RequestMapping("/api/")` so that it will be `@RequestMapping("/api")`.

Your class should look like follows,

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String,Object> home() {
        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the problem with your server-side. all you will have to do is do a component in your server-side and it will solve the issue. or refer [here](https://medium.com/@buddhiv/what-is-cors-or-cross-origin-resource-sharing-eccbfacaaa30)

follow this code:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
            try {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pre-flight");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization, content-type," +
                    "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've chosen to annotate your app, you must provide the `@CrossOrigin` annotation for each method individually. That means you must also do:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/", maxAge = 3600)
    @RequestMapping("/login/")
    public Map<String,Object> login() {
     /* ... */
    }
```

Reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#_enabling_cors

Answer (score 0):

Instead of annotating every method with `@Crossorigin` you can use a `filter` in `web.xml` as mentioned below

Add Below filter to `web.xml` file.

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Dependency for the mentioned jar is given below.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thats it -Done.