# ANGULAR 10 Keycloak blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, keycloak

I have my app in angular 10 and access by httpclient to keycloak EndPoint to access to my app, angular 10 code.

```
const data = {
  'username': username,
  'password': password
};
return this.httpClient.post(environment.loginOAUth, data);
```

Where environment.loginOAUth = 
keycloal is configured as:

- client-protocol:openid-connect
- type access: confidential
- Valid Redirect URIs: myAppURL and
- Web Origins: +

Error:

> from origin 'myAppURL' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I think the problem is in my angular code since I have tried anything from internet comments. Could you heo me ? Thank you in advance

Comment: set http://localhost:4200 as root_url

Comment: what version do you use? if keycloak 8 onwards, you have to change the Access Type option to Public

Comment: keycloak version 4.8.3.Final

Comment: root_url is set to localhost now and does not working aither

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your Angular app.
To resolve it in localhost you can proxy your requestes with this configuration on package.json "ng serve":

```
ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.json
```

And, in the proxy.conf.json put the redirect to that domain:

```
{
  "/auth": {
    "target": "http://keycloakcpath",
    "secure": true,
    "logLevel": "info",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: I have created proxy.conf.json  file and changed my running options, It does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem with Angular 10 in front with keycloak-angular 8.1.0/keycloak-js 12.0.4 and Spring Boot in the back.
Try to add configuration to your backend. In my case this worked:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
            try {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pre-flight" + new Date().toString());
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization, content-type," +
                "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }

    }
}
```

[Original answer post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620597/cors-angular-and-springboot-request-blocked)

Another even simplier

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${server.frontendUrl}")
    protected String frontendUrl;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(frontendUrl.split(",")).allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
    }
}
```

Where *server.frontendUrl* value **http://localhost:4200** is defined in application.properties